# excel conditional if drop down list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a drop down lists paired with data validation in my excel sheet.

What i want to accomplish is 'if answer in drop down list = a' display drop down questions for 'first'. 'if answer in drop down list = 'b'' display drop down questions for 'second'. etc etc.

Is there a way or method that can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Use Name Manager under Formulas. If your first drop down as "Product A", "Product B" then you will name the arrays with the options for A as "Product A", and options for B as "Product B"

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in which Headers are 'First' and 'Second' and the question options for each are below the relative column. Highlight, go to the 'Formulas' Tab and select 'Create from selction'. Ensure 'Top Row' is the only one ticked click OK.

Create your first drop down list like you usually would in let's say cell A1
Create your second one, but in source type '=INDIRECT(A1)'

That should have sorted it.